# How to create a Google Analytics report of one metric as a function of another?

Tags: google-analytics

I want to set up a Google Analytics timeline report of one metric as a function of another. Example scenario:

1. The user does something on `page #1`. On that page there is dynamically generated content, e.g. an image banner with different text.
2. The user interacts with that content which generates event hits with different labels (`A`, `B`, `C`... dynamically generated based on the dynamic content on the page).
3. The event hits with their labels are sent via POST to Google Analytics using the [measurement protocol](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/protocol/v1/parameters).
4. The user does (or does not) visit `page #2`

I want to be able to measure the efficiency of each event label defined as:

```
Efficiency = (Number of users visited page #2) / (number of hits for event label)
```

Ideally this should be able to give me an idea which are the most efficient event labels for:

- particular hour of the day
- particular day of the week
- particular months of the year

Looking at the goal funnels it seems possible to define only funnels based on a sequence of page views, not as a function of event labels (not talking about dynamic ones at all). It also seems not possible to set it up as a content experiment because the labels are dynamic and everything should be measured long term, new labels can be added, older ones can be removed/restored etc.

Is that possible to do what I am looking for with Google Analytics?

Comment: I'm not sure it will work but try to set calculated metrics in GA admin. https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/6121409?hl=en but you cant use event label in calculation because event label is define as string. Instead you can use event value.

Comment: @JacekSzymański thanks but unfortunately it seems impossible to create a formula based on event labels at all, which means dynamic ones are totally impossible.

Answer (score 0):

Adding a Custom Dimension should resolve the problem. Here are the steps using Google Tag manager (GTM):

- Add a custom dimension say BannerName in Google Analytics (GA)
- Define variables in GTM say BannerText and BannerClick (Depending on
  your page markup, css selector rules may have to be applied)
- Pass BannerText value in custom dimension BannerName, it will provide
  you pageviews and all GA data as you have for any dimension.

To capture clicks:

- Set up a trigger that filters clicks only on specific element in
  question
- Pass captured values (Click text) in dimension BannerClick

Basically you will have pageview (visit) data and event (click) data collected in GA and can process it the way you want. 
BannerClick variable is optional if you are able to capture banner clicks using existing click variables {click element, click text, click url}. In that case, you can just filter in reports based.
You may use calculated metric directly to further simplify calculation if you want as suggested by Jacek.

Comment: You are suggesting a solution which includes GTM but the question is about GA only. The main part of your answer describes how to capture page views and events and that is not what I am asking for. The pages are already sending the event data and the page view data. The problem is how to generate the report and as I noted in the reply to Jacek unfortunately calculated metrics don't offer such ability. Feel free to correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: As I understand you need to calculate 
'Efficiency = (Number of users visited page #2) / (hits on event label)'
event label as such would be text and would not be used to calculate a metric. In similar context, I have used something like http://easycaptures.com/fs/uploaded/946/0921642364.png to calculate click thru rate on banner image.
I assume your report would look like 
**Label Hits Clicks Efficiency**
A m1 n1 m1/n1
B m2 n2 m2/n2
C m3 n3 m3/n3

Comment: you are right about the formula, I edited the question to clarify that. However calculated metric won't do because the label are many, not even a fixed number and they are dynamically generated. It would be possible to create 100-200 calculated metrics for each label considering they change all the time.